# A Linked list that is dynamic in terms of data it holds

Tags: c, data-structures, struct, linked-list, union

I have been reading about linked list lately. A normal linked list (after this i would call it ll only) has the following

```
typedef struct linked_list{
    int data;
    struct linked_list *next;
}linked_list;
```

The issue here is the type of data we stored is fixed to int. I would need to make a different one to hold float data, char data respectively.
So, i thought of instead why not implement it in this manner:

```
typedef struct linked_list{
    union data{
        int data;
        char data;
        float data;
    };
    struct linked_list *next;
}linked_list;
```

This brings me a closer to my desire of a ll which is dynamic in terms of data too. 
Now, I have two questions: 
1. Is this efficient?
2. This will force me to use a generic pointer has an argument for push function. Are generic pointers a good thing?

There is also one more implementation that I thought of:

```
typedef struct linked_list{
    void *data;
    struct linked_list *next;
}linked_list;
```

What are the issues regarding this?

Comment: Seems to me you are trying to reinvent [Object Oriented Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming), where you can extend your data to be one of many different inherited types.

Comment: You are right. Using the `void *data` is the way to have a generic mean to store any data type. If your list holds different data types, the better way is to have an extra member in your function to tell what is the data type, like `int data_type`. So, when you are traversing the list, by the `data_type` you know how to dereference the `void*` pointer to the correct type.

Comment: @campescassiano I thought about it and i'm going to store type in the start node. As start node will have two members type and node of sll. Start is itself a structure. I just want to know the efficiency of this approach.

Answer (score 1):

- Is this efficient?

With the union defined you will have three different facets to look at. Also, the union overlays an object with different types of interpretation. I would look at things from the view of extensibility. With that, you probably can create in the future a union with bigger data struct. This increases the memory consumption in the whole program slightly.

- This will force me to use a generic pointer has an argument for push function. Are generic pointers a good thing?

It's not guilty.

From my side, instead of generation of the list structure for specific underlying data. You can try to reuse (understand more generic implementation) like here:
https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/list.h

https://algorithmsandme.com/linked-list-implementation-in-linux-kernel/

In the kernel, lists interface you have create your data structure and embed a list inside. I hope this will help to expand your possibilities.

Comment: I have checked both the links. They have improved my understanding of optimization through macros and inline functions. I have also read about the generic implementations. Thanks for pointing these things out.